# Modular Linear Equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am revising for one of my Computer Science exams, and a repetitive question keeps coming up; however it's very maths based. And I suck at mathematics.

*Question $3)$*

Consider the following two modular linear equations separately,
which are to be solved for the variable $x$:

$$\begin{align}
6 + 4x &\equiv 0 \pmod {16}\\
-11 + 7x &\equiv 0 \pmod {17}\\
\end{align}$$

$a)$ Solve each equation separately. Provide either the result for $x$ if the equation is *solvable*, or write *“not solvable”* if the equation cannot be solved. $3$ marks.

Please feel free to change the values whatever you wish, because I know people will suspect this may be homework which isn't the case.

If somehow could demonstrate how to solve a question like this in the least mathematical way possible, I'd be really grateful. I just don't even know where to start, in lectures my just speaks in mathematics terms which I can't take in.

Comment: If the modulus is small (as is the case here) you can always attack these by trial and error...just try every possible value!  In some cases, like your first equation, you should see a problem...if $16|(6+4x)$ then we must have $4|(6+4x)$ but that would imply that $4|6$ which is not true, hence that congruence is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

See the first congruence-

$6+4x\equiv0\space(mod16)$

So,$16\vert(6+4x)$

So,any factor of $16$ must also divide the equation if it is true.

So,$8\vert(6+4x)$.

But it is not true.Why?

[image]

To find it out I plotted the graphs of the equation $y=6+4x$ and $y=8x$ and overlapped the two graph papers.

Clearly the lines of the two equation will never intersect even when extended indefinitely.So,they do not have any solution.So, the first equation is not true (in other words **not solvable**).

Try the same thing for the second equation.

Hope my answer helps!!

Comment: You may also plot the graph $y=16x$ and see the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

This is the least mathematical way I can think of (in Python):

```
for x in range(0,17):
    if (-11 + 7*x)%17 == 0:
    print x
    break
else:
    print "not solvable"
```

To make it just a little better you can reduce the number of tests you need putting $17/\gcd (17,7)$ as the end of the test range. You can also reduce the number of divisions using the remainder from the previous iteration and subtracting 17 if it exceedes that value.

PS. I didn't make it a generic function so you can't use it for your homework :)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that my answer is too late, but I joined this community from about a month. It may help you or others.

This is a classic problem which can be solved by the chinese remainder theorem (look it up if you'd like) (if something in my solution you don't understand, check (number theory topic) + " Brilliant Wiki" the wikis will help you):
$$6+4x \equiv 0 \pmod{16}$$
$$\implies 4x \equiv -6 \equiv 10 \pmod{16} \tag{1}$$
$$-11+7x \equiv0 \pmod{17}$$
$$\implies7x \equiv 11 \pmod{17} $$
$$\implies7x \equiv28 \pmod{17}$$
and since $\gcd(7,17)=1$, we can divide by $7$ to get: (properties of modular arithmetic) 
$$\implies x \equiv4 \pmod{17} \implies4x \equiv16 \pmod{17} \tag{2}$$
Now, we can simply let $y=4x$ and solve for the congruences in $(1)$ and $(2)$:
\begin{align*}
  y &\equiv 10 \pmod{16} \\
  y &\equiv 16 \pmod{17} \\
\end{align*}
The first congruence tells us that $y=16k+10$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we can substitute that in the second congruence:
$$16k+10 \equiv 16 \pmod{17} \implies 16k \equiv 6 \pmod{17} $$
and now we keep adding $17$s on $6$ until we reach a number divisible by $16$
$$ 16k \equiv 6 \equiv 23 \equiv \dots \equiv 176 \pmod{17} $$
$$ \implies k \equiv 11 \pmod{17} \implies k=17j+11 \ (j \in \mathbb{Z}) $$
Now we can substitute that in $y=16k+10$ to get
$$y=16(17j+11)+10=272j+186 \implies y \equiv 186 \pmod{272}$$
$$ \implies 4x \equiv 186 \pmod{272} $$
$$ \implies 4x = 186 + 272z \tag{for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$}$$
$$ \implies 4x + 272l = 186  \tag{$l=-z$} $$
This is a classic linear diophantine equation.

Since $\gcd(4,272)=4 \nmid 186$, the equation has no integer solutions for $x$ and $l$ (Bézout's identity).

Now I didn't actually know what the problem exactly requires or if $x$ should be an integer or not, but I hope this helps you.